# Allow a user to read some other users' home directories

Tags: linux, permissions

I am new to system administration and I have a permission related query. I have a group called `administration`. Inside the `administration` group, I have the users `user1`, `user2`, `user3`, `superuser`. All the users are in the `administration` group. Now, I need to give permissions to the user `superuser` to be able to view the `/home` directory of the other users. However, I do not want `user1`, `user2`, `user3` to see the home of any other user other than himself. (That is, `user1` should be able to see only `user1`'s home and so on).

I have created the users and groups and assigned all the users to the group. How should I specify the permissions for the `superuser` now?

In other words, I'm thinking of having two groups (say `NormalUsers` and `Superuser`). The `NormalUsers` group will have the users `user1`, `user2` and `user3`. The `Superuser` group will only have the user `Superuser`. Now, I need the `Superuser` to have full access on the files of users in the group `NormalUsers`. Is this possible in Linux?

Comment: How is this different from [your previous question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91465/allow-a-user-to-view-the-home-directory-of-other-users)?

Comment: In my previous question, I was more concerned with editing the /etc/sudoers file and making the user as a partial administrator. Here, I am trying to modify the permissions of a local user. Yeah, it's similar to what am trying to achieve, but am trying to approach a different method here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If the users are cooperative, you can use [access control lists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list) (ACL). Set an ACL on the home directory of `user1` (and friends) that grants read access to `superuser`. Set the default ACL as well, for newly created files, and also the ACL on existing files.

```
setfacl -R -m user:superuser:rx ~user1
setfacl -d -R -m user:superuser:rx ~user1
```

`user1` can change the ACL on his files if he wishes. Even if `user1` is cooperating, new files may accidentally be unreadable, e.g. when untarring an archive with restrictive permissions, or because some applications deliberately create files that are only readable by the user (e.g. mail clients tend to do this).

If you want to always give `superuser` read access to `user1`'s files, you can create another view of the users' home directories with different permissions, with [bindfs](http://code.google.com/p/bindfs).

```
mkdir -p ~superuser/spyglass/user1
chown superuser ~superuser/spyglass
chmod 700 ~superuser/spyglass
bindfs -p a+rD-w ~user1 ~superuser/spyglass/user1
```

Files accessed through ~superuser/spyglass/user1 are world-readable. Other than the permissions, `~superuser/spyglass/user1` is a view of `user1`'s home directory. Since `superuser` is the only user who can access `~superuser/spyglass`, only `superuser` can benefit from this. This method is automatic and `user1` cannot opt out.

Comment: On my system, the permissions and the username are swapped: `setfacl -R -m user:superuser:rx ~user1`.

Comment: Nice! A small question: do you imply that i) the ACL solution will not guarantee that all new files and folder added later on will also be readable by superuser, while ii) the bindfs solution does guarantee that all files and folders added under the user1 tree in all future will always be readable? :)

Comment: one more thing: in this setup, one may have some cases in which some files, other than folders, were executable before, and the X will keep these executable also from superuser, right? Is there a way that the superuser can *only* read + execute dirs / read all files, and not read and execute the files that were executable from before, in a way that this is guaranteed "for all future under user1!?

Comment: @Zorglub29 With ACL, user1 can make files unreadable deliberately (`chmod`, `setfacl`) or accidentally (e.g. untarring an archive, saving an email). With bindfs, the view is created dynamically and user1 can't prevent it. With bindfs, you can use `D` instead of `X` to only apply executability to directories (I'm not sure the D flag existed when I posted this answer, but it's been around for a long time now).

Comment: Aaahh, excellent with the D flag :) . Do you think you could update your answer with it? That may answer the initial question even better:) .

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I was reading the doc of ```bindfs``` in more details, wonder now if the ```-r``` option may be an even simpler way to get a read-only view: "-r, -o ro Make the mount strictly read-only.  This even prevents root from writing to it. ". I am currently using a command in the kind of ```sudo /usr/bin/bindfs -r -u $(id -u) -g $(id -g)  src dest```, works like a charm :) .

Answer (score 12):

You can use ACLs to grant access to a particular directory to an arbitrary group.

For example, if you ran `setfacl -m g:dba:rwx /home/foo`, then members of the dba group would have rwx permissions on it, regardless of which group owns the directory.

You'll probably also want to set the "default" ACL (the ACL for newly-created objects inside the directory) to also include this permission.

Comment: yeah, exactly..I found out the same too but still not sure if it is a good idea to grant ACLs in the server for the LDAP users.

Comment: @Ramesh Well, if they're users on the system (because you're using nss-ldap, sssd, etc.), then I'm not sure why it wouldn't be OK.

Comment: I was trying to replicate this in test bed. When am logging in as the user (for example foo), I am seeing a warning message as "the permissions should be set to 644". I do believe the warning can be ignored. But, I do not want the lab users to know that their user accounts has been compromised. When I change the rwx to just r in the setfacl command, I am not able to see the foo's directory.

Comment: @Ramesh You need +x to actually go through directories. I'm not sure what's telling you that a directory should be 644, that's silly, it should be 755 or similar. But either way, the user will see a + in ls's permission field, and can run getfacl to see it—its not secret.

Comment: Alright, I was getting the warning message, User's $HOME directory must be owned by user and not writable by other users. I removed the write permission in the setacl command and now I do not see the warning message.

Comment: The problem here is that `user1`, `user2`, etc will have root level access via `sudo` through the `administrator` group. ACLs will be completely ineffective at restricting access.

Comment: @Swiss he's trying a different approach according to his comment, so there isn't any sudo involved, AFAIK.

Answer (score -3):

Unfortunately, there's not really any way to directly do this on vanilla Linux.

You might be able to create a new group in sudoers for the partial-admins with a white list of acceptable commands you want to allow them to run.

However, to achieve exactly what you are asking for, you would have to use Apparmor or SELinux to achieve what you want. Unfortunately, neither of these tools are easy to set up and use, and examples are far outside the scope of a quick answer here.

Comment: Linux has supported ACLs for a while now. ACLs let you do this.

Comment: Yeah, I just found that solution and updated the answer. However, I still don't know if it can be used in the server and that too for LDAP users.

Comment: @derobert From what I understand, it is impossible to give someone root level permissions via sudo while simultaneously using ACLs to limit access. You have to use SELinux or another MAC to achieve that.

Comment: I think when OP says the user "superuser", he means that literally – not root.