# Allow group to r/w in folder owned by a specific user

Tags: permissions, chmod, chown

I have a group `manager` and an user `user1`.

`user1` will create a directory by example in the webserver path `/var/www/user1Project`.

How to allow the group `manager` to r/w in any directory owned by `user1` ?

I already tried to add group `manager` to `user1`. But it did not solved my problem. A user from `manager` group is not allowed to write in `user1Project`. I do not know why.

Comment: You have two options (or even more), first: add `maganer` to `user1` groups, 2nd: add an ACL for specific file or directory. Which one is what you want? You can also use `chgrp -G` or use GID-bits for permissions. Tell us what limitations you wanna set, and what you have tried.

Comment: the problem description is incomplete: How much do you want to automate the process? I.e. is user1 supposed to do anything manually? Second, should the sought solution apply to any directory that user1 creates, or only to selected directories (say, directories within a subtree of a file system)? Third, how does user1 create the directories under consideration - manually through `mkdir` on the command line, or from the desktop, or by a script?

Comment: Adding user1 to manager is not sufficient because newly created resources will assume the primary GID of the creating process by default.

Comment: See also the quasi-duplicate [Allow a user to read some other users' home directories](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/91488/allow-a-user-to-read-some-other-users-home-directories)

Comment: @Gilles I posted another post on another forum and found a solution. http://serverfault.com/questions/796224/user-member-of-group-and-permissons/796246#796246

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is quite special and you could not manage this by using the legacy permissions architecture of an unixoid system. The closest approach to your intention is using [ACLs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs). Issue the following command (optionally as superuser):

```
setfacl -d -R -m g:manager:rwx /dir/of/user1
setfacl -R -m g:manager:rwx /dir/of/user1
```

The first command sets the default permissions to the directory so that they apply to newly created files (by user1). The second command sets the actual rights of the folders and files recursively.

Note, that the ACL infrastructure does not apply to the Apache Webserver. Apache only cares about the legacy permissions (user/group/others permission). So inside the webfolder every file/folder must be in the `www-data` group and every file must have at least read permissions for `www-data`. Folders should have the execute permissions for `www-data` for the Index searching.

**Update:**

To force the newly created files inside a directory to inherit the group of this directory set the gid bit of the directory:

```
chmod g+s /web/directory
```

Newly created files inside `/web/directory` will then inherit the group of `/web/directory`

Comment: without `x` permission, that other user cannot cd to the directory. Update your answer.

Comment: that is right - x then will be applied to all folders recusively but not to the files. sorry for that...

Comment: This is a problem. I currently working inside my Apache Webserver so ACL will not help me this time ... I am allowing `user1` to create directory (through FTP) inside `/var/www` so the directory belong to `user1`. Is there any way to force the user to create the directory wich belong to `www-data` group ?

Comment: Is it possible to also inherit the parent's folder permission in addition to the group?

Comment: `setfacl -R -m g:...` perhaps. At least on Linux `setfacl` doesn't like mixing the parameters the way you did (`-R` would be an argument to `-m`). I think `user1` should also be able to add the ACL to their directory, so using superuser powers may not be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to being part of the group, you have to set write permission on the directory:

```
 chmod 770 /var/www/user1Project/example_dir
```

(use 775 if you want the world to have read permission, which is more likely on a web directory).

Also realise that the user manager has to re-login after being added to the group `user1`.

If you want every directory created by `user1` to be writeable by the group members of group `user1`, you can set:

```
umask 0002
```

which will result in directories created with permissions `rwxrwxr-x`.

Comment: Is there any way to automate this cmd? Because I will not be aware when `user1` will create a new folder

Comment: You can set the umask, I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Set directory group to manager:

```
chgrp -hR manager /your/target/directory/path
```

And then, add set-GID-bit to your permission, so if `user1` changes anything, the group will be able to write again:

```
chmod g+s /your/target/directory/path
```

Answer (score 2):

When `user1` creates the dir, it will be owned by `user1:user1`. This means user:group. Assuming they are in the same group, let's call it `group1`, `user1` needs to make the group `group1` the group owner of this directory. So:

```
chown :group1 dir`
```

Now for the `manager` to be able to r/w directories, the group permission bits need to be set to 7, ie `rwx`. This is done so:

```
chmod g+rwx dir
```

But, when `manager` creates a file it is owned by `manager:manager`, so he needs to `chown` it to `:group1` for the group permissions to apply to `group1`, the same way `user1` had to do.

There's a trick that copies the group ownership from the parent dir. It's the special group permission bit, SGID. This can be done so:

```
chmod g+s dir
```

Finally, newly created items (files and directories) take on the permissions from their parents, plus there's a last modifier called `umask`. It inverts single bits of permissions if they are set, and has the same format of 4 octal digits. Usually it is 0002 or 0022. 0002 means the second bit from the right will be masked (or inverted). For example, with `umask` 0022, when you create a new dir in another dir with permissions rwxrwxrwx, the new dir will get permissions rwxr-xr-x.

So if `manager` has `umask` 0022, he will also have to `chmod` his dirs and files to 7 to give the group full access to them.

Comment: Newly created files take permissions from the system call creating them, not their parent (except if you mean ACL:s, but you didn't mention them.) Also, `umask` doesn't _invert_ any bits, it _clears_ (masks) them. Inverting would imply that a zero could also turn into a one. (though I guess "inhibit" could be used in the same sense here, but it doesn't feel usual in this context.)

Comment: "It inverts single bits of permissions if they are set". Read carefully please. As for the system calls, I'm not that advanced.

Answer (score 1):

`setfacl` looks the best deal for you. Make sure that `acl utilities` are installed. To check if it is already installed

In Redhat bases systems do :

```
yum list acl
```

In Debian based systems do

```
dpkg -l acl
```

If not already installed, for Redhat bases systems do :

```
yum install acl.x86_64 # Or use dnf for later versions of Fedora and so
```

In Debian based systems do

```
dpkg install acl
```

Enable acl on the file systems, my modifying the /etc/fstab

```
UUID=your_uuid_here   /partition    filesystemtype   options,acl   0   2
```

Note `,acl` is the only part added, now remount the partition

```
mount -o remount /your_partition_here
```

<sup>(That completes the setup part, you might not do this if `acl` already installed).</sup>

---

**Applyting setfacl**

```
setfacl -m g:manager:rw file /var/www/user1Project #you need root privileges
```

You're good to go